# How to change value in Request.Url in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working in asp.net.i want to assign a value in Request.Url ,i know that is readonly but is there another way to change the url.(i don't want to redirect.)

Actually i have passed query string parameter from one page and redirected to second page. now inside second page (Page_Load) i have received that parameter value and i want my url don't show that parameter inside query string.

```
txtcontactsearch.Text = Request.QueryString["email"];
string myNewUrl = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
```

I want my browser shows myNewUrl  url.

Comment: if you use POST rather than GET your variables are sent as data, not on the URL..

Comment: You can encrypt contents passed in query string.

Comment: Use `POST` method.

Comment: @BugFinder   yes you are correct, i want to send that variable as a url, but don;t know how.

Comment: @MUT  how to use post for  changing url by removing a specific parameter from url.

Comment: @user3928524, why you want to send variable as url? Just `post` that variable.

Comment: and access it on other page using `Request.Form["email"] `

Comment: @MUT actually i am sending my variable via <a> tag from page1 click  to page 2, thus when page 2 PageLoad() runs i want to remove that parameter from query string(and my url)  again..so the url is not change or appended by parameter.

Comment: share your code.

Answer (score 0):

A proper way to do that is to use the HTTP post method ,
but if you only want to hide the query string value in url, you can use java script to change the url without reloading the page. As example below.

```
`
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
   window.history.replaceState("", "", "New URl");
   }
</script>
```

`
you may send your new url from your controller action by using Viewbag.